# Error in configuring SQL server in WSL

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 10: Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.19)

WSL: Ubuntu 16.04

Following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu). I get an error in Step 4 when running `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`

```
➜  x git:(master) ✗ sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
[sudo] password for devlin:
Locale en_GB not supported. Using en_US.
Choose an edition of SQL Server:
  1) Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
  2) Developer (free, no production use rights)
  3) Express (free)
  4) Web (PAID)
  5) Standard (PAID)
  6) Enterprise (PAID)
  7) Enterprise Core (PAID)
  8) I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.

Details about editions can be found at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=852748

Use of PAID editions of this software requires separate licensing through a
Microsoft Volume Licensing program.
By choosing a PAID edition, you are verifying that you have the appropriate
number of licenses in place to install and run this software.

Enter your edition(1-8): 2
The license terms for this product can be found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-server or downloaded from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=855862

The privacy statement can be viewed at:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=853010


Choose the language for SQL Server:
(1) English
(2) Deutsch
(3) Español
(4) Français
(5) Italiano
(6) 日本語語
(7) 한국어어
(8) Português
(9) Русский
(10) 中文 – 简体体
(11) 中文 （繁体））
Enter Option 1-11: 1
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
Configuring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000003
      Message: fd != -1
   Stacktrace: 00007f15f48346e3 00007f15f41e76ba 00007f15f17e73dd
      Process: 2186 - sqlservr
       Thread: 2187
  Instance Id: 5b1c8da3-1358-48d3-a563-25468ff2ab69
     Crash Id: 577efbb6-5740-4ee5-92f6-0ddc0eea685f
  Build stamp: 1fdc73777d57c7c1942f388381b8f6ac2c50f005e35b808c23f54dfecdf59384
*********** PANIC CORE DUMP GENERATION FAILED **********
Attempt to launch handle-crash.sh failed with error 0x0000000C
/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/invokesqlservr.sh: line 15:  2185 Aborted                 (core dumped) sudo -EH -u mssql
 /bin/bash -c "$CMDLINE"
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Attempting to start the Microsoft SQL Server service failed.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 04/2021**: Still not supported

From this docs:[Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu)

> At this time, the Windows Subsystem for Linux for Windows 10 is not supported as an installation target.

So your installation is not supported

Comment: Wow. Missed that one. I guess I skipped it because it wasn't in red

Comment: I didn't notice it. Is there any alternative option?

Comment: Still not supported in 2021, the note should be super red... expected it to work. Thought it was working, as both is from MS :(